# VS 2022 C# Forms: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, exception

// Script Explanation

I'm trying to create a sort of timer which counts using a loop and a counter integer on startup, which saves the amount of seconds to a .txt file and stops when the program stops.

Because I'm using a while loop for the counting I have to do that in a separate thread to not stall the UI from updating and therefore count inside the separate thread and then invoke the text to the UI function.

The script will be at the bottom however thought I'd include this explanation for easier understanding.

// Issue

This all works fine, it updates the text label to show the seconds elapsed just fine, however when trying to close the application it throws an exception which I tried to fix by putting a bool check on when it should be counting and should not be counting inside the while loop instead of just running the while loop when true is true. I activate the bool at the start of the script when defining it and I disable it on the Form1_FormClosing event, but it still throws the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'
```

// My Script

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace PC_Timer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool Counting = true;
        private int count = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists("count.txt"))
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText("count.txt");
                count = int.Parse(text);
                label1.Text = count.ToString() + " Seconds";
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllText("count.txt", "0");
            }

            new Thread(Loop).Start();
        }

        private void Loop()
        {
            while (Counting)
            {
                count++;

                label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                    label1.Text = count.ToString() + " Seconds";
                });

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Counting = false;
            File.WriteAllText("count.txt", count.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

// Final Remarks

Maybe there is a better way to go about this, than doing it in a while loop since they are pretty inefficient however this is supposed to be a simple program for solo use purposes, which is why I went about doing it with a while loop because its what I'm most comfortable with.

I also tried to check if IsHandleCreated was true, which did work but I don't think it dealt with the exception, since I could not publish it because of one or multiple errors whchi Visual Studio was unable to determine the cause of.

Anyways what should I be doing different for the Invoke function to not get stuck when exiting the program?

Comment: This is a classic race condition. It's actually more difficult to fix that one might think. An obvious idea would be to use a lock to prevent the thread loop from trying to invoke while the form is closing, but that's likely to cause deadlock if the `Form1_FormClosing()` is blocked waiting for the lock when the loop is trying to call `Invoke()`.  Have you considered using a `Timer` to update the label instead of a background thread? That would avoid the problem.

Comment: I would suggest that you run your loop within a `Task` and then use a `CancellationToken` to kill it within `FormClosing`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Have had experience in more LUA style code so I guess I just thought a loop with a Sleep within it would be the more simple path to take, since I've never worked with Timers before. First I'm just gonna try the method the other person who replied gave and then I'll try to use a Timer and then get back to you, thanks for the reply!

Comment: I don't think it will help using a Task with a CancellationToken, since the underlying problem will still exist. But go ahead and try it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Just looked into it a bit since my last reply. I'm not very experienced in C# and the Task and CancellationToken looked a bit too complicated for me. I might look into it in the future however for now I'll try the timer, thanks again!

Comment: @MatthewWatson You were completely correct. Timer was much easier haha! First time using StackOverflow so I'll try to find a way to make your answer marked as the answer, thank you!

Comment: I'll copy my comment into an answer if you like.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you, kinda new to posting questions on here! Marked it as the right answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic race condition. The loop has already checked that `Counting` is `true` and is about to call `Invoke()` when the main UI thread closes the form, and thus the `Invoke()` fail.

It's actually more difficult to fix that one might think. An obvious idea would be to use a lock to prevent the thread loop from trying to invoke while the form is closing, but that's likely to cause deadlock if the Form1_FormClosing() is blocked waiting for the lock when the loop is trying to call Invoke().

Have you considered using a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-7.0) to update the label instead of a background thread? That would avoid the problem